# $p$ prime , $n\in \mathbb{N_0},f= \sum_{j=0}^{n}a_jx^{jp}\in\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$, show that $f=g^p,g\in\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ exists

Tags: abstract-algebra

I could prove that if it exists it is unique but I could not show the existence for such a function

My uniquencess proof draft

Assume $a^p=g^p$, then $a^{p}-g^p=0$ thus if $g=\sum_{k=0}^{m}a_kx^k$ and $g=\sum_{k=0}^{l}g_kx^k $

$(a_0+\dotsb+a_mx^m)^p=\sum_{k_0+\dotsb+k_m=p}{p\choose k_0,\dotsc,k_m}\cdot a_0^{k_1}\dotsm a_mx^{{m}^{k_m}}$

and

$(g_0+\dotsb+g_{l}x^l)^p=\sum_{k_0+\dotsb+k_l=p}{p\choose k_0,\dotsc,k_l}\cdot a_0^{k_1}\dotsm a_lx^{{l}^{k_l}}$

(I still have not proved this part) but the only way the difference can be zero is when the both polynomials are exactly the same

Comment: This is not true as stated: consider $f = a_0$. Is every element of $\Bbb Z_p$ of the form $b^p$?

Comment: isn't it ? The map $a\mapsto a^p$ is injective, no?

Comment: @guidoar: presumably the OP is using $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to refer to $\mathbb{F}_p$ here.

Comment: yes but there is only one field with p elements

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** note that in $\Bbb Z_p$ we have $a_i= a_i^p$, and $(x+y)^p = x^p+y^p$.

Comment: I cannot find the solution, I will try some more...